# SQl Query to get an output that resembles the image

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sum, gaps-and-islands

[image]

I would like to get output the way its shown in the image attached
and the way the input is organized is also shown in the image attached.

Thanks!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPXfl.png

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not explicit about the logic, but I understand this as a gaps-and-island problem, where each island starts with a `start` status.

Here is an approach that uses a window count of starts to define the groups, then aggregation:

```
select container, grp, sum(units), min(move_time) start_time, max(move_time) end_time
from (
    select t.*, 
        sum(case when status = 'start' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by container order by move_time) grp
    from mytable t
) t
group by container, grp
order by container, grp
```